# Get container id from tag name

Tags: docker

I am trying to copy a file from a container using `docker cp`. I built the container using `docker build -t math-gsl-ubuntu-2004 .` and after running the container image with `docker run` a file `/math--gsl/Math-GSL-0.41.tar.gz` is generated in the container. To copy the file back I can do

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                  COMMAND                 CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
b651512240f2        math-gsl-ubuntu-2004   "./entrypoint.sh 2.6"   3 hours ago         Up 3 hours                              boring_lamport
ee008e7b8f01        44f63ff22dea           "./entrypoint.sh"       3 hours ago         Up 3 hours                              heuristic_liskov
```

then I note from the above output that the ID is `b651512240f2` and I can issue `docker cp b651512240f2:/math--gsl/Math-GSL-0.41.tar.gz .` from the host to get the file out of the container.

Now I want to determine the container ID programatically from the name `math-gsl-ubuntu-2004`:

```
$ docker inspect --format="{{.Id}}" math-gsl-ubuntu-2004
sha256:866d21bece6aaf63496a5b173cafa37a25e21d22f7d34c1bbae4c602526c419b
```

but this does not match the container ID of `b651512240f2`. What am I missing?

Comment: You are using image name in `docker inspect` command instead you need to be using container name which would be at the end of docker inspect output.

Comment: @Setu How can convert image name to container name? Or how can I set the container name? Now the container name is `boring_lamport` from the output of `docker ps` but I did not set that name myself, so I guess it was generated?

Comment: `docker run -d --name mycontainername math-gsl-ubuntu-2004`?

Comment: @atline If I run that command I get output `3e1431f9490dd56408e609c708ead565e2c6bece69897c867fa1f870dee35bd4` but container name does not change. It is still `boring_lamport`

Comment: yes, you can give specific name to container and use use the same to while copying

Comment: @HåkonHægland This is just an example, you should use the correct command for you `docker run`, if you type `docker ps -a`, you could see that container with the new name there.

Comment: @atline *"This is just an example..."* You mean replace `mycontainername` in the command you suggested with `boring_lamport` ? But then I need to know that the name is `boring_lamport` that is the issue I am trying to solve since I did not create the name `boring_lamport` myself. I need to start with the image name `math-gsl-ubuntu-2004` and from that get the container name

Comment: Wow, so you can't decide container name... Then `docker ps`  could get all containers running, then the second column is the image name "math-gsl-ubuntu-2004". You surely could loop all containers to decide which container using the image name "math-gsl-ubuntu-2004", then know what container you needed. Just a little complex...

Comment: @JeevanRao *"you can give specific name to container.."* How can I do that? I cannot see that `docker build` has an option to set the container name, it can set the image name with `-t` option as far as I can see. But not the container name

Comment: @HåkonHægland updated in answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

command to build an image

`docker build -t math-gsl-ubuntu-2004 .`

It will create an image with name `math-gsl-ubuntu-2004`

After building an image, you have to create/launch a container out of it,

to do that

`docker run -it --name mycontainer math-gsl-ubuntu-2004 bash`

and then

`docker cp mycontainer:/math--gsl/Math-GSL-0.41.tar.gz .`

---

To Fetch container name

```
docker ps -a | grep <image:tag> | awk '{print $1}' | head -n 1

examples:

docker ps -a | grep ubuntu | awk '{print $1}' | head -n 1

docker ps -a | grep ubuntu:18.04 | awk '{print $1}' | head -n 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `docker run -v` option, you can cause your process to directly write content out to the host directory:

```
docker run -v $PWD:/math--gsl ... math-gsl-ubuntu-2004
```

Note that this hides everything in that directory in the image and replaces it with the host directory content, and then starts the container, and writes after that are reflected in the host directory.  If the workflow is what you say – the *container* generates the tar file – this will work for you and is less fragile than `docker cp`.